# Jquery – What is the best structure for a little wysiwyg

Tags: jquery, structure

*Stackoverflow warns me that my question might be subjective while I'm creating it, I've read the faq but I'm still not sure if I am allowed to ask it. Sorry in advance if this question is subjective, please close it if that's the case.*

I am learning jQuery while working on a little tool I want to create for myself. I am a designer and I want to be able to preview how the fonts look on the web to make my typographic choices. The tool is a type tester, under the form of a wysiwg.
I want to create my own because none of the online tools that exist let you change the width of the text, that's an important feature as readiblity also depends on the number of words displayed on each line of text.

I have 2 different testers that can be accessed under tabs so you can compare 2 configurations of your text. Each elements has a unique id, I read that the fatest jQuery selector is the `$('#myID')` selector.
I have completed the application with my basic knowledge of jQuery, and everything works. I don't need the app to run on old browsers (I use html5 contenteditable) as it is designed only for me and designers friends but still want to optimize the code. So I would like to know what would be the best structure for this app.

Here is a simplified version of my markup:

```
<div class="pane">
    <div id="testercontent1" class="preview">
      <p class="editable" contenteditable="true">Here is the default placeholder text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tools">
      <form autocomplete="off">
        <select id="fonts-tester1">
          <option value="Arial" selected="selected">Arial</option> 
          <option value="Courier New">Courier New</option> 
          <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option> 
          <option value="Times New Roman">Times New Roman</option> 
          <option value="Trebuchet MS">Trebuchet MS</option> 
          <option value="Verdana">Verdana</option> 
        </select>
        <input type="checkbox" class="bold" id="bold1" /><label>Bold</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="italic" id="italic1" /><label>Italic</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="uline" id="uline1" /><label>Underline</label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="allcaps" id="allcaps1" /><label>Allcaps</label>
        <input type="radio" class="pleft" name="radio1" id="pleft1" checked="checked" /><label>Alignleft</label>
        <input type="radio" class="pcenter" name="radio1" id="pcenter1" /><label>Center</label>
        <input type="radio" class="pright" name="radio1" id="pright1" /><label>Alignright</label>
        <input type="radio" class="pjustify" name="radio1" id="pjustify1" /><label>Jusitfy</label>
        <div class="type-size"><label>Size</label><input type="text" id="size1" class="spinner" value="13" /></div>
        <div class="type-leading"><label>Leading</label><input type="text" id="lineheight1" class="spinner" value="20" /></div>
        <div class="type-kerning"><label>Kerning</label><input type="text" id="kerning1" class="spinnerkerning" value="0" /></div>
        <div class="word-spacing"><label>Word spacing</label><input type="text" id="wordspacing1" class="spinnerwordspacing" value="0" /></div>
        <div class="column-width"><label>Column width</label><input type="text" id="colwidth1" class="spinnercolumn" value="600" /></div>
        <input type="button" id="resetall1" value="Reset all" />
      </form>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- This is repeated a second time with all the id numbers set to '2' -->
```

### Apply changes

And here is an example of how I (inefficiently) apply changes to the text with my set of tools (I repeat this "format" a lot, for each property I can change on the text):

```
$('#uline1, #uline2').click(function(){
    var num = this.id.substr(-1);
    $('#testercontent' + num).toggleClass('previewuline');
}); 

$('#kerning1, #kerning2').change(function(){
    var num = this.id.substr(-1);
    $('#testercontent' + num).css('letter-spacing', $(this).val()+'px');
});
```

### Reset changes

Also, if you noticed, I have a "Reset all" button that resets all the parameters I changed in my toolset and "reinitialize" the text properties back to default. For that I change all the values back to default but I am sure there is a much efficient way to do this (that is related to how I apply changes):

```
$('#resetall1, #resetall2').click(function(){
    var num = this.id.substr(-1);
    $('#testercontent' + num).css('font-family', 'Arial').css('text-align', 'left').removeClass('previewbold').removeClass('previewitalic').removeClass('previewuline').removeClass('previewallcaps').css('font-size', '13px').css('line-height', '20px').css('letter-spacing', '0').css('word-spacing', '0');
    $('#bold' + num).removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#bold' + num + '-checkbox span').removeClass('disabled');
    $('#italic' + num).removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#italic' + num + '-checkbox span').removeClass('disabled');
    $('#testercontent' + num + ' p').css('width', '600px');
    $('#guide' + num).css('left', '630px');
    $('#testercontent' + num).css('color', '#000000').css('backgroundColor', '#ffffff');
    $('#typecolor-selector' + num).ColorPickerSetColor('#000000');
    $('#typecolor-selector' + num + ' div').css('backgroundColor', '#000000');
    $('#typehex' + num).attr('value', '000000');
    $('#bgcolor-selector' + num).ColorPickerSetColor('#ffffff');
    $('#bgcolor-selector' + num + ' div').css('backgroundColor', '#ffffff');
    $('#bghex' + num).attr('value', 'ffffff');
    $('#tester' + num + ' span').removeClass('checked');
    $('.pleft' + num).addClass('checked');
    $('#colwidth' + num).attr('value', '600');
    $('.ruler-off' + num).addClass('checked');
    $('#ruler' + num).hide();
    $('#guide' + num).removeClass('guide-on').css("left","670px");
    $('#tester' + num + ' form').get(0).reset();
    $.uniform.update('#tester' + num + ' select');
    $('#codebox' + num).slideUp(250);
});
```

I've started to look into objects but couldn't figure out the best structure for this specific need.
I am aware that I am asking for a lot, but what I simply need is a hint on how I should organize the code (from a top left perspective). That would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the question is bad or off-topic, however I imagine you are going to get a lot of TL;DR.  BTW, if this is just websafe fonts (looks that way so far), fine, if you are using other fonts, make sure the site is not world accessible if you have licensing issues.

Comment: thanks @Orbling, I'm aware of the problem. This will be password protected as I actually have a feature where you can upload any ttf or otf font to test.

Comment: Aye good, that probably violates most commercial font software licenses as is, they tend to be exceptionally restrictive.  But sounds interesting.